I need the fastest way to perform transaction
I working on solana trading bot,  i am using @solana/web3 for blockchain communication and raydium amm pools for performing swaps.
I need the fastest way to perform transactions and know if it processed or rejected. Now I am using this code
const transactionHash = await connection.sendTransaction(transaction);
const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

await connection.confirmTransaction({
  blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
  signature: transactionHash,
}, 'processed');

But it takes usually 1 minute to perform transaction or get rejected and it is too long

Are you using the public RPC endpoints?
You could change RPC providers and manually benchmark to see which one is the fastest. I'd recommend checking out Triton One but a full list can be found here https://solana.com/rpc
